# Why do two SQL queries gave me different result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote two queries and thought they would give the same result, but it didn't happen. Could you please explain to me why?
**1)**

```
SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM (SELECT user_id, date(time) as date, COUNT(order_id)
                        FROM user_actions
                        WHERE order_id NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM user_actions WHERE action = 'cancel_order')
                        GROUP BY user_id,date(time)
                        HAVING COUNT(order_id) = 1)t1
GROUP BY date
```

**2)**

```
SELECT date(time) as date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM user_actions
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM (SELECT user_id, date(time), COUNT(order_id)
                        FROM user_actions
                        WHERE order_id NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM user_actions WHERE action = 'cancel_order')
                        GROUP BY user_id,date(time)
                        HAVING COUNT(order_id) = 1)t1)
GROUP BY date(time)
```

---

Comment: I don't know exactly what `date(time)` means, but I'd guess `date` <> `date(time)`

Comment: Needs sample data illustrating the different results with the two queries. Also I think it would help if you stated in your own words why you think they should be the same (since they are written differently and as mentioned above they use different functions related to date / time).

Comment: There are a few things that could be happening. Most obviously, in the first you'll only get users whose ids are unique on a given day. In the second query, you've get all users which are unique on **any** day. So even if the user is not unique on 2023-01-01, it'll still show up for 2023-01-01 if it was unique on 2022-06-15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **1)**, the subquery t1 is retrieving all the users that had one (and only one) action per day of type other than 'cancel_action' and the day of this action, then the top query is counting how many of these users existed each day.

In **2)**, the subquery t1 is doing exactly the same as in 1), but then you are getting the user_ids and counting users per day of action. The problem is, even if the users exist in the set of users that had at most one action per day at some date, that doesn't mean that some of these users could have had more than 1 action on the same day in **different** dates.

Example:

user_id = 1

- 1 action on 02/01/2024
- 1 action on 02/06/2024

user_id = 2

- 1 action on 02/01/2024
- 1 action on 02/04/2024
- 2 actions on 02/05/2024

t1 returns:

| user_id | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/01/2024 | 1 |
| 1 | 02/06/2024 | 1 |
| 2 | 02/01/2024 | 1 |
| 2 | 02/04/2024 | 1 |

Then, in **1)** counting from t1 by date results in:

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 02/01/2024 | 2 |
| 02/04/2024 | 1 |
| 02/06/2024 | 1 |

But in **2)** you will get that extra date 02/05/2024 when user_id 2 made two actions, so you will get:

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 02/01/2024 | 2 |
| 02/04/2024 | 1 |
| 02/05/2024 | 1 |
| 02/06/2024 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

it's a matter of filtering.
Your first query will only consider users with one order not cancelled per date.
Then count the distinct users per date.

Your second query will retrieve all users with one order not cancelled per date.
Then for each of these users count the distinct users per date.

So, imagine the following:

| ID | User | Date | Order | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User2 | Date1 | OrderID1 | action1 |
| 2 | User1 | Date2 | OrderID2 | cancel_order |
| 3 | User1 | Date1 | OrderID3 | action1 |

Your first query will return

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Date1 | 2 |

Record #2 is excluded.

Your second query will return

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Date1 | 2 |
| Date2 | 1 |

As User1 has a legit order on Date1, the order on Date2 is also counted. Record #2 is no more filtered out.